# How to unit test stateless material-ui components? functions are not accessible from the outside

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, react-hooks

In some of the material-ui examples they have internal functions inside the functional component. Those are unaccessible for unit testing, am I losing something?

What I've could done is just either convert it into a `class` component or extract those functions outside and bind the params inside...

IE: https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  ...
}));

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return 'Select campaign settings...';
    case 1:
      return 'What is an ad group anyways?';
    case 2:
      return 'This is the bit I really care about!';
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

export default function HorizontalLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const steps = getSteps();

  function isStepOptional(step) {
    return step === 1;
  }

  function isStepSkipped(step) {
    return skipped.has(step);
  }

  function handleNext() {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
      newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }

    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
  }

  ...

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            labelProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
      <div>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
            </Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
              Reset
            </Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>
            <div>
              <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                Back
              </Button>
              {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleSkip}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  Skip
                </Button>
              )}

              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleNext}
                className={classes.button}
              >
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in this example functions like `isStepOptional`, `isStepSkipped`, 
`handleNext` are not accessible from the outside of the component

from a test file would be necessary to access those functions in order to unit-test them.

And another good question would be if those functions are not re-defining on every prop change of that component...

Isn't it a little bit anti-pattern?

Comment: You should not test implementation but functionality. By checking if isStepOptional, isStepSkipped,  handleNext is set correctly, you are testing just the implementation details. These are likely to change. If that happens, you would have to rewrite the test even if the component still works because you just renamed a variable. Instead you should test if the component renders the expected code if the props are correct and clicks are executed.

Comment: Well behaviour test are also included but sometimes you want/need to unit-test some functions in order to ensure the good behaviour of a particular function